# HTMLAgilityPack - You need to set UseIdAttribute property to true to enable this feature

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use HTMLAgilityPack with VS2008/.Net 3.5. I get this error even if I set the OptionUseIdAttribute to true, though it is supposed to be true by default.

```
Error Message:
 You need to set UseIdAttribute property to true to enable this feature

Stack Trace:
    at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.GetElementbyId(String id)
```

I tried version 1.4.6 and 1.4.0, neither worked.

Version 1.4.6 - Net20/HtmlAgilityPack.dll

Version 1.4.0 - Net20/HtmlAgilityPack.dll

This is the code,

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
    HtmlNode table = doc.GetElementbyId("tblThreads");
```

This didn't work either,

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument { OptionUseIdAttribute = true };
    doc = web.Load(url);
    HtmlNode table = doc.GetElementbyId("tblThreads");
```

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after loading your `HtmlDocument`, what does the document look like. i.e. does it load properly?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine after web.Load(url);

Comment: Can you specify the url?

Comment: Sorry, it's a private url. The same code works fine on VS2010 with .Net 4.0. But I need to make it work on a VS2008 project.

Comment: @user471317 as I answered your question are you going to award me the bounty?

Comment: I 'Accepted' your answer. I guess points doesn't automatically go to that poster? I see you got the points now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I used [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) on the 1.4.0 HAP Dll. I navigated to the HtmlDocument class and could see that the GetElementById method looks like this:

```
// HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
/// <summary>
/// Gets the HTML node with the specified 'id' attribute value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The attribute id to match. May not be null.</param>
/// <returns>The HTML node with the matching id or null if not found.</returns>
public HtmlNode GetElementbyId(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("id");
    }
    if (this._nodesid == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(HtmlDocument.HtmlExceptionUseIdAttributeFalse);
    }
    return this._nodesid[id.ToLower()] as HtmlNode;
}
```

I then got ILSpy to analyze "_nodesid", because in your case for some reason it is not being set. "HtmlDocument.DetectEncoding(TextReader)" and "HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader)" assigns value to "_nodesid".

Hence you could try an alternative method to read the content from the URL whereby the "_nodesid" value will be definitely assigned e.g.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        doc.Load(stream);
    }
}
var table = doc.GetElementbyId("tblThreads");
```

This approach ensures that "HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader)" is called, and in that code I can see that _nodesid will definitely get assigned, so this approach *may* (I haven't compiled the code I've suggested) work.