# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in HtmlAgilityPack.dll

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use HTMLAgilityPack with VS2008/.Net 3.5. I get this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in HtmlAgilityPack.dll
>
> Additional information: You need to set UseIdAttribute property to
>   true to enable this feature

This is the code;

```
public string kmail = "deneme";
    public string ksifre = "deneme123";
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.GetElementbyId("username_or_email").SetAttributeValue("Value", kmail);//bilgileri gir
        doc.GetElementbyId("password").SetAttributeValue("Value", ksifre);
        HtmlElement button = Browser.Document.GetElementById("allow");//tıkla
        button.InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

I tryed old versions of DLL but didn't worked.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Have you set UseIdAttribute to true, like they tell you to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTMLAgilityPack - You need to set UseIdAttribute property to true to enable this feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455916/htmlagilitypack-you-need-to-set-useidattribute-property-to-true-to-enable-this)

Comment: Your code in your question doesn't show you setting the UseIdAttribute. Please try that out and update your code.

Comment: Is the exception occurring on line before: doc.GetElementbyId("username_or_email").SetAttributeValue("Value", kmail);//bilgileri gir

Comment: HtmlExceptionUseIdAttributeFalse = "You need to set UseIdAttribute property to true to enable this feature" why i get this ?
also;
HtmlExceptionRefNotChild = "Reference node must be a child of this node"

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455916/htmlagilitypack-you-need-to-set-useidattribute-property-to-true-to-enable-this) may help you

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to resort to use `SelectSingleNode()` passing XPath to select node by `id` attribute, for example :

```
doc.DocumentNode
   .SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='password']")
   .SetAttributeValue("Value", ksifre);
```